# Redirect the first row towards one direction and the second somewhere else

Tags: talend

I need to separate flows for my rows, depending on a given field. Let's say if my rows have three fields, field1, field2, field3, I need to send for each value of field1 I encounter the first one on a certain path and the others on another path

How can I solve that? Should I keep the first row using a tFilterRow and then redirect join its output with its input on a tMap?

Answer (score 1):

tMap is the one. You can initialize a boolean context value to false to detect your first row, then use filters in yours tMap outputs with this boolean value. On your first output, you change your boolean value to true.

Edit: with a value memory. Declare an Object type context value in your job (field1Values).

[tJava]
|
|onSubjobOk
|
[your iteration component] -- [tMap] -- output1 -- [tJavaRow]

In tJava

> context.field1Values = new HashMap();

In tMap filter for output1

> (!((HashMap)context.field1Values).containsKey(currentRow.filed1));

In tMap filter for output2 (does not appear)

> ((HashMap)context.field1Values).containsKey(currentRow.filed1);

In your tJavaRow

> ((HashMap)context.field1Values).put(input_row.field1, true);

Comment: I need to do that for each distinct value of field1, can you provide a more detailed example please?

Comment: Hum, sorry I did not understand everything (I have bad english).
It is pure java answer, initialize a HashMap in your context, then play with containsKey and put to detect the first time you have a value

Comment: what's the  iterationComponent?

Comment: This component does not exists, it is the component you use to read your datas (tInputFile, bddInput, ..)